# LPC17xx internal pull-ups on JTAG etc

Tags: jtag, cortex-m3, lpc1768

The the NXP LPC17xx Cortex-M3 family has internal pull-up resistors on some important pins such as the JTAG, NMI, Bootloader-select pin etc.

While reading the data-sheet I learned that the pull-up is internally connected to a voltage source of 2.3V to 2.6V. The core itself runs at 3 to 3.3V.

I see that 2.3V is good enough to give a reliable logic high level, but why didn't NXP just pulled up all these pins to VCC instead?

What is the advantage in doing so? NXP clearly didn't did it that way just for fun..

Comment: A guess would be that the high voltage (3.3V) is only present at the input to the on-chip regulator, not distributed around the chip, and the pullup is to the internal core voltage, which I don't see specified.

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

The only reason I can think of is to provide a weak pull-up so a wide variety of controllers can manipulate the pins with open drain switching as it's very common.
[image]

Also the Pull's are disabled for the TCK

Comment: Yes, sure. It's UM10360.pdf:  http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10360.pdf On page 101 you'll see the TCK pin along with the footnote [5] which indicates the pull-up to 2.3 to 2.6v.

Comment: This isn't an answer and you should delete it - leave it as a comment under the question.

Comment: It wouldn't let me comment.. need 50 reputation??

Comment: Just added a snap shot from the user manual that shows the TCK pin in interest.